# ¿ Cuando uso Inertia.js debo prescindir de Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, inertia.js

tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy haciendo un CRUD de users, pero en vez de hacer las peticiones en el **componente vue de user** lo quiero hacer llamandolo desde un store de user.js para que este la logica que se comunica con el server centralizada.

Mi **componente vue User**:

```
<template>
    <simple-layout>
        <template slot="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Usuarios</h1>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" @click="create">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template #body>

            <div class="container">
                <!-- Modal -->
                <modal name="crud-modal" class="p-4 rounded">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div v-if="modalType === 'create' || modalType === 'edit'" class="text-center mx-5">
                                <h2 v-if="modalType === 'create'">Crear usuario</h2>
                                <h2 v-else>Editar usuario</h2>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="w-100 text-left">Nombre</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="currentUser.name"  name="name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="w-100 text-left">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" :value="currentUser.email"  name="email">
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else class=" h-100 text-center">
                                    <h2>Eliminar usuario</h2>
                                    <p>¿Estas seguro que deseas eliminar este usuario?</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-around">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="sendRequest">OK</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="cancel">Cancelar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </modal>
            </div>

            <!-- Displaying errors -->
            <div class="container" v-if="$page.errors | $page.flash.message">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" :class="{'bg-danger': $page.errors, 'bg-sucess':$page.flash.message}">
                        <div  class="text-red-500">
                            {{ $page.errors.title[0]}}
                            {{ $page.flash.message}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Display stored users -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-9">
                                        {{user.name}} | {{user.email}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" @click="edit(user)">Editar</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click="remove(user)">Eliminar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </simple-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import SimpleLayout from './../Layouts/SimpleLayout'
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        components: {
            SimpleLayout
        },
        props:['users'],
        data(){
            return{
                currentUser:null,
                modalType:''
            }
        },
        methods:{
            showModal() {
                this.$modal.show('crud-modal');
            },
            hideModal() {
                this.$modal.hide('crud-modal');
            },
            edit(user){
                this.currentUser = user;
                this.modalType = 'edit';
                this.showModal();
            },
            remove(user){
                this.currentUser = user;
                this.modalType = 'remove';
                this.showModal();
            },
            create(){
                this.currentUser = {
                    name:'',
                    email:''
                };
                this.modalType = 'create';
                this.showModal();
            },
            sendRequest(){
                if (this.modalType === 'create') {
                    this.store(this.currentUser)
                }
                else if (this.modalType === 'edit') {

                }
                else if(this.modalType === 'delete'){

                }
                this.hideModal();

            },
            cancel(){
                this.hideModal();
            },
            ...mapActions('user', [ 'store' ]),
        }

    }
</script>
```

En el metodo `sendRequest()`, dentro de  `this.modalType === 'create'` llamo a la funcion del store de user, que mas abajo (`...mapActions('user', [ 'store' ])`) la estoy invocando.

Mi **store de User.js**:

```
const { default: Axios } = require("axios");

export default {
    namespaced:true,
    state: () => ({
       user:{}
     }),
    mutations: {
        setName(newName){
            state.name = newName;
        },
        setEmail(newEmail){
            state.email = newEmail;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        store(user){
            let form = {};
            form.name = user.name;
            form.email = user.email;
            this.$inertia.post('/user',form);

        }
    },
    getters: {
        getName(state){
            return state.name;
        },
        getEmail(state){
            return state.email;
        }
     }
  }
```

Si os fijais, ahi estoy llamando a **inertia** , en el **action** `store`. Pero no me lo reconoce, y lo estoy llamando en este fichero para modularizar la app, no quiero tener peticiones http en cada componente repitiendo codigo.

Mi fichero **app.js**, donde esta fichero main de vue, es este:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';

import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue';
import { InertiaForm } from 'laravel-jetstream';
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.esm';
// Import the styles directly. (Or you could add them via script tags.)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
//vue-js-modal
import vmodal from 'vue-js-modal'
//vuex
import Vuex from 'vuex'
//store
import store from './store/index'
// //axios
// import axios from 'axios'

Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } });
Vue.use(InertiaApp);
Vue.use(InertiaForm);
Vue.use(PortalVue);

// Customs
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(vmodal);
Vue.use(Vuex);
// Vue.use(axios);

const app = document.getElementById('app');

new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),
    store
}).$mount(app);
```

El error que me da es:

```
app.js:66435 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

found in

---> <User> at resources/js/Pages/User.vue
       <Inertia>
         <Root>




app.js:67698 TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

Basicamente me esta diciendo que, dentro de User.js (el module de vuex para usuarios que he creado) no reconoce `this.$inertia` 
¿Quiere decir esto que cuando use inertia.js no tiene sentido usar vuex ?

Comment: bueno amigo te digo que con inertia.js creo que ya no se necesario vuex ya que contamos con el HandleInertiaRequests en la ruta app/http/middelware la cual al establecer los datos qeu se muestran en vue en la variable de inertia.page.props lo cual no se hace necesario vuex ya que tenemos esas variables serian globales, y accesible a cualquier componente. utilizando la variables. no estoy seguro lo que digo alguien me puede confirmar. o apenas hagas las pruebas con los componentes les confirmo.

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que el contexto de vuex es distinto al de Vue. me pasaba cuando quería usar axios dentro del store como se hace en nuxtjs.

```
const instance = axios.create({
    //
})

Vue.prototype.$axios = instance
Vuex.Store.prototype.$axios = instance
```

supongo que se debería hacer algo asi

```
Vuex.Store.prototype.$inertia = this.$inertia
```